# Git Large files detected error after removing the large file from the folder

Tags: git, github

I have a folder named 'data' and unknowingly I pushed the large file (more than 100 MB). But after the error, I removed the file from the folder and try to push the code. And it's giving the same error.

```
    remote: error: GH001: Large files detected.
```

I tried to remove the cache as well with following command.

```
       git rm --cached data/bike_trip_data_july.csv
```

It's giving error :

```
         fatal: pathspec 'data/bike_trip_data_july.csv' did not match any files
enter code here
```

Comment: Try to [revert the commit in your remote](http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/git-howto-revert-a-commit-already-pushed-to-a-remote-reposit.html).

Comment: @Jezor Yes, I revert the commit. And after that?

Comment: Try to, if you don't have too much history after committing that large file, to reset --hard to the commit prior the one including your large file, and force pushing to GitHub.

Comment: @Jezor, thank you. Reverting seems the only option after long struggle.

Comment: No reverting won't remove the large file from the GitHub repo. Only force pushing will